# Convert one dimensional array to multiple

Tags: javascript, arrays

Im not sure if my question is right but I want to convert this array

```
["url1","url2","url3","url4","url5","url6"]
```

I want it to become like this

```
["url1"],
["url2"],
["url3"],
["url4"],
["url5"],
["url6"],
```

How can I achieve this on javascript?

Thanks

Comment: We don't ask much but we do ask that people asking questions add the code they've attempted to their question as a [mcve]. Otherwise we're doing all the work for you, and SO isn't really that kind of site.

Answer (score 3):

you can map your array to return a new one for each element

```js
const data = ["url1","url2","url3","url4","url5","url6"];

console.log(data.map(one => [one]));
```